# mysql is_numeric sql injection

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pagination in my webpage. So I want to add a line to my query if I have a post from pagination:

```
$q="";
if(isset($_POST["inpi"])){
    $in = $_POST["inpi"];
    if(is_numeric($in)){
        $q = "and c.id < '$in'"; // add this to mysql
    }
    else{die("something is wrong!");}
}
```

So I can't use prepare statments here.

```
select k.user, c.id, c.from, c.sent, c.message, c.recd from chat c
inner join cadastro k on c.from=k.id
where `from`=? and `to`=? $q
```

notice the $q variable, it will have no value if post is empty or the and c.id < '$in'.

is it secure enought?

Comment: If you are verifying the input using is_numeric then I think you don't have to worry about sql injection in this case. Since for sql injection there must be some quotes and strings involved.

Comment: You absolutely can use prepared statements here. Are you using PDO? You can add something to the query string and the `array` used to hold the values at the same time.

Comment: @tadman I'm using mysqli

Comment: PDO does make it easier, but `mysqli` isn't impossibly hard.

Comment: Here's an [example of doing it with `mysqli` that could be adapted](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always accumulate arguments as you go and build it out like this:

```
$query = "SELECT ... WHERE `from`=? AND `to`=?";
$binds = array("ss", &$from, &$to);

if (isset($_POST["inpi"])) {
  $query .= " AND c.id < ?";

  $$binds[0] .= "i";
  $binds[] = &$_POST["inpi"];
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $binds);
```

I haven't tested this, but it's based on [this code](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli) and may require some adjustments to work.

PDO's `execute()` function takes an `array` straight up, it's way easier to work with.

Comment: oh, it is amazing! thank you very much for your help, friend!